# Read timeout implement for WebService HTTPS call

Tags: java, web-services, https, timeout

I am trying to implement read timeout(timeout after specified duration) for WebService call over HTTPS.
Its working fine over HTTP but its not over HTTPS.
Any help will be appreciated.

I am using Axis 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global timeout for the JVM through a system property.  What have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried using Stub timeout and System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "1000")